# I wanna limit value of a quantity that user put on the text field (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I want a user can input no more than 100 in my textfield.
If a user put more than 100 --let's say 123--, the text will show 100 instead of 123.

here is my code

```
TextField(
                                  controller: qtyController,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  onTap: () => qtyController.text = '',
                                  inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter. digitsOnly,
                                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3),
                                  ],
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `onChanged` callback to listen to the changes

```
    TextField(
      controller: qtyController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      onTap: () => qtyController.text = '',
      onChanged: (val){
       if (val.isNotEmpty) {
        if(int.parse(val)>=100) {
          qtyController.text = "100";
        }
       }
      },
      inputFormatters: [
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3),
      ],
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    )
```

Comment: thx. it solve the value limit problem, but when I type 123, then it changes to 100, then I can't edit the number. the number can't be deleted.  it stuck at 100. how can i solve this?

Comment: Hope you can make use of the backspace button

Comment: yeah, man. I use the backspace button. but it won't do the trick. but anyway, it's not a major issue. thx a lot .

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to supply an `onChanged()` callback to a TextField or a TextFormField. Whenever the text changes, the callback is invoked.

A more powerful, but more elaborate approach, is to supply a `TextEditingController` as the controller property of the TextField or a TextFormField.

Details on here:https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `maxLength` property to set the maximum characters allowed in the `TextField`. Read more about it [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/maxLength.html).